# Why is my UIPickerView not displayed?

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

hi i am creating the picker view example with xib not with the help of code but after running the project i am not getting the picker view over the screen.shall i any one provide the solution for this problem. i already gave datasource,delegate connections to the files owner also.

Answer (score 6):

You wont see the picker until you set the **data source** and the **delegate** correctly. However you provide no code in your question which makes it hard to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, 
Xcode 4.5 -

Add a pickerview to a view and a button.
If AutoLayout is turned on, it will display both...
If Autolayout is off - it will only display the button...

UNTIL - you connect up the DataSource and Delegate CORRECTLY...

So, you can check the Autolayout button to see if it appears, then 
you know that your datasource and delegate are not set up correctly

You have to implement the protocols in the .h file 
Then there are about 4 methods you have to code - 
Number of components
Number of Rows
Title For Row, and a few others to select rows.